# Filtrar tabela por valor de botão (Datatable)

Tags: asp.net, datatable

Eu estou fazendo umas alterações em um projeto asp.net de um cliente, e me deparei com uma tabela construída em `dataTable()`.

Existem alguns botões que deveriam realizar um 'filtro' baseado no 'tipo' de cada item da tabela, porém isso não foi implementado no backend.

Como gambiarra, me foi solicitado filtrar direto pelas funções do `dataTable()`, já que o prazo está curto.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function () {
                var todos = $('#todosf').click();


                $('#gridCotacao').DataTable({
                    "processing": true,
                    "ajax": {
                        "url": "@Url.Content("~/home/grid")",
                        "type": "POST"
                    },
                    "columns": [
                        { "data": "CPFCNPJ" },
                        { "data": "Nome" },
                        { "data": "Numero" },
                        { "data": "Data" },
                        { "data": "Premio" },
                        { "data": "Status" },
                        { "data": "Tipo" },
                        { "data": "IdCotacao" }
                    ],
                    searching: false,
                    paging: true,

                    "columnDefs": [
                        { "targets": '_all', 'searchable': true },
                        { "data": "Tipo",
                          "targets": 6,                        
                          "render": function (row, type, val, meta) {
                            if (val.Tipo == 'Cotacao') {
                                return '<img src="@Url.Content("~/image/edit.png")" width="18" />';
                            }
                            else {
                                return '<img src="@Url.Content("~/image/apolice.png")" width="18" />';
                            }
                            return val;
                        }
                        },
                        { "targets": 7, "visible": false }
                    ]

                });

            });
```

A tabela é construída pelo controller :

```
[HttpPost]
[AuthorizationFilter]
public ActionResult Grid()
        {
            Grid grid = new Grid();

            Usuario user = new Usuario();
            user = (Usuario)Session["ObjetoUsuario"];

            //Serviço Cotacao        
            List<GridItem> gridL = new List<GridItem>();

            gridL = new ListaCotacaoServico().ListarCotacao(user, "pt-BR");


            foreach(var item in gridL)
            {
                grid.data.Add(new GridItem()
                {
                    CPFCNPJ = item.CPFCNPJ,
                    Data = item.Data,
                    Nome = item.Nome,
                    Numero = item.Numero,
                    Premio = FormatacaoHelper.Moeda(item.Premio, CulturaEnum.en_US),
                    Status = item.Status,
                    Tipo = item.Tipo,
                    IdCotacao = item.IdCotacao
                });
            }

            //for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
            //{
            //    grid.data.Add(new GridItem() { CPFCNPJ = "819682276" + i, Data = i + "/01/2019", Nome = "Fulano de Tal" + i, Numero="111"+i, Premio = "1.200," + i, Status = "Pendente", Tipo = "Apolice", IdCotacao = "1"+i });
            //}

            return Json(grid, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

    }
```

Eu preciso filtrar pelo atributo "Tipo", em cada botão

```
<a class="btn btn-link m-1 " href="##" id="todosf">
                <span class=""> TODOS</span>
            </a>

            <a class="btn btn-link m-1" href="##" id="cotacaof">
                <span class="">COTAÇÕES</span>
            </a>

            <a class="btn btn-link m-1" href="##" id="apolicef">
                <span class=""> APÓLICES</span>
            </a>
```

Eu li a documentação mas não estou conseguindo uma solução prática, alguém poderia me ajudar ?